# Calling a Web Service in a Console Application Using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: web-services, permissions, scheduled-tasks, console-application, network-service

I need to sync a sql server database with data hosted on another web server. I wrote a C# console Application to call a web service to give me the data hosted on the other web server. I set up a job to run every 10 minutes in task scheduler in "Server Manager" for Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.

If I run the console application myself then everything works as it should. If I run it in the Task Scheduler using my username it also runs as it should. However if I run it using the NETWORK SERVICE user, which is what I need to do, then the app stops running once I try to contact the web service.

Where do I give NETWORK SERVICE the permissions to call a web service?

Comment: Is the wcf service secured in anyway? Do you get an exception?

Comment: This the error I receive: `Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Dashboard_Import_Job.Clarizen.Clarizen.Login(String userName, String password, LoginOptions options)
   at Dashboard_Import_Job.Program.Main(String[] args)`

Comment: Here is the inner Exception: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 63.150.165.231:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& excepti)`

Comment: I guess the certificate for the ssl handshake fails. Can you try adding the server certificate and it's CA in the Computer certificate store see http://chrisjakeway.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/windows-importing-a-certificate-for-a-service/

Comment: How do I know what certificate I should add? Where are certificates located? It didn't seem like the web services needs certificates. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the their is the local services on my company servers are not allowed to call web services. I need to make a new internal account. Thanks Rene for your help.